# Paypal and custom button in express checkout

Tags: paypal

Is it allowed by paypal to use a custom image for the "buy now" button using the express checkout?

In the paypal profile the "button creator" tool allows to insert a custom image but in all the documentations about the express checkout flow it looks that you must use this image

https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_dg_pay_w_paypal.gif

Answer (score 0):

Correct, for the Website Payment Standard buttons you can use your own images.  However for Express Checkout you would want to use the PayPal generated buttons.

Comment: So I guess the correct answer is "You have to use that button if you are using Express Checkout, no exceptions".

Comment: No he would not WANT TO. That's the whole point of his question. In the in-context checkout I was able to use a custom button but struggling getting it working with 2017 version